# How do I pass List <PackageInfo> between activities in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to pass a List of PackageInfo between multiple activities in my application. Is it possible to do this using an Intent?

Comment: is it really that necessary??, you can again get package info in second activity, if you do want some operation to be done based on package, pass array of package names `(com.google.)` from one activity to other

Comment: Akhil is right. And you can also make that Arraylist static so that it can be accessed in all activities.

Comment: I have to show the icon and package name in the second activitie, and run application when I click on the icon, that's why I want to pass List of PackageInfo

Comment: so pass the package name in second activity accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can again get package info in second activity, if you do want some operation to be done based on package, pass array of package names (com.google.) from one activity to other.

Answer (score 0):

You can put anything in the intent's extra, the object just have to be parcelable (seems complicate but it's not at all!).

You have example here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Maybe a concrete list is parcelable (like ArrayList) I don't remember.

The other way I'm thinking about is maybe to use the shared preference, I know you can put a set in there, if you wan't to access your list everywhere that can be a way to achieve it.

Hope I help !

Answer (score 0):

In that exact case you can query the PackageInfo list in every activity. But in the common case, when I have to share non-parcelable objects through multiple activities, I use to create a singleton class for that. Note that it would consume memory, so make sure to dispose the singleton when it's not needed anymore.

For example, for PackageInfos it would look something like this:

```
public class SharedPackageInfos{

     private SharedPackageInfos(){}

     private static SharedPackageInfos _current;

     public static SharedPackageInfos getCurrent()
     {
         if(_current == null)
         {
             _current = new SharedPackageInfos();
         }

         return _current;
     }

     private List<PackageInfo> packageInfos;

     public List<PackageInfo> getPackageInfos()
     {
         return _packageInfos;
     }

     public void setPackageInfos(List<PackageInfo> packageInfos)
     {
         this.packageInfos = packageInfos;
     }


     public static void dispose()
     {
         _current = null;
     }

}
```

And from the activities call

```
SharedPackageInfos.getCurrent().setPackageInfos(myList); //save a list


List<PackageInfo> packageInfos = SharedPackageInfos.getCurrent().getPackageInfos(); //retreive a list
```